# REGEX: Exact match a word followed by 1 space followed by digits

Tags: regex

I want to exact match a string followed by exactly one space and then numbers.
I.e. input would be Acc 1234, should evaluate to true.

Here is my regex that I've tried:

```
[^(\\WAcc\\W)[ ]{1}\\d]
```

This however fails for inputs (AccA1234 or Acc 1234 ACA, or Acc1234). How to I get my regex to match to my input (Acc 1234) exaclty?

Comment: *match to my input (Acc 1234) exaclty* : `^Acc \d+$`

Comment: Why do you expect a match for `AccA1234` if there is no space inside?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it evaluates to true, when I execute my regex. I don't expect it to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\W` is a non-word character. I'm guessing you were looking for `\b`, the word boundary matcher, instead.

I'd try this regex:

```
^\bAcc\b \d+$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^[^\s]+\s\d+$
```

1. `^` - asserts beginning of line
2. `[^\s]+` - match anything other than space, one or more characters
3. `\s` - match single space, \s is for space match
4. `\d+` - one of more digits
5. `$` - marks the end of line

Comment: Where in my regex would I place this?

Comment: that is the entire regex